# Одинаковые названия секторов в диаграмме Google Sheets

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Допустим у меня есть таблица со столбцами `марка авто`, `модель авто`, `количество`. Я строю по этим данным две диаграммы. Одна показавыет зависимость между моделью и количеством, вторая - между маркой и количеством.
В столбце `марка авто` значения ячеек могут повторяться, поэтому на следующую таблицу мне строится диаграмма из 4-ех секторов с двумя дублями `Nisan`. Как сделать так, чтобы на этой диаграмме сектора было три и они соответствовали маркам?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Диаграмма строится по диапазону листа. Нужно создать доп. таблицу с объединением данных

Comment: `Nissan` пишется через две `s` ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Диаграммы не производят никаких вычислений, кроме агрегационных. Поэтому, вам нужно либо подготовить данные перед построением, либо поставить галочку "Агрегировать" в настройках самого графика.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или же сгруппируйте ваши данные заранее с помощью [QUERY](http://=QUERY(A1:C5,%22select%20A,%20sum(C)%20group%20by%20A%22))

```
=QUERY(A1:C5,"select A, sum(C) group by A")
```

И уже на этих данных стройте график.